# Checking installation status of an application on windows through a c++ code

Tags: windows

I want to know whether a particular application is installed on my windows machine or not  through a c++ code (and after that I will sink that application's setting on my machine which is present on a given server.)

Comment: I read this post earlier but could not find it helpful...

Comment: Maybe rephrase your question.